# cannot combine with and functions in R

Tags: r, function, with-statement

Could somebody please point out to me why is that the following example does not work:

```
df        <- data.frame(ex =rep(1,5))
sample.fn <- function(var1) with(df, mean(var1))
sample.fn(ex)
```

It seems that I am using the wrong syntax to combine `with` inside of a function.

Thanks,

Comment: The help page for `with` specifically warns you NOT to use it in functions. Learn to use "[".

Comment: the error really has nothing to do with `with` `with(df, sample.fn(ex))`

Comment: @BondedDust actually, it doesn't. It certainly *should*, but to see the `Warning` you have to look in `?subset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant by learning to use "[" (actually"[["):

```
> df        <- data.frame(ex =rep(1,5))
> sample.fn <- function(var1) mean(df[[var1]])
> sample.fn('ex')
[1] 1
```

You cannot use an unquoted `ex` since there is no object named 'ex', at least not at the global environment where you are making the call to `sample.fn`. 'ex' is a name only inside the environment of the `df`-dataframe and only `df` itself is "visible" when the `sample.fn`-function is called.

Out of interest, I tried using the method that the `with.default` function uses to build a function taking an unquoted expression argument in the manner you were expecting:

```
samp.fn <- function(expr) mean( 
                  eval(substitute(expr), df, enclos = parent.frame())
                               )
samp.fn(ex)
#[1] 1
```

It's not a very useful function, since it would only be applicable when there was a dataframe named 'df' in the parent.frame(). And apologies for incorrectly claiming that there was a warning on the help page. As @rawr points out the warning about using functions that depend on non-standard evaluation appears on the `subset` page.